# HTTPPost2 send form data

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, httppost

How could I post data to a url with Content-Type: multipart/form-data

I doing this, but it reports error to me:

```
SET @httpPostCallStatus = HTTPPost2(
    "https://url-post-data",
    "multipart/form-data",
    "code=CODE_ALL_ABSOLUTE&amount=49&type=absolute&duration=24&minPurchaseAmount=49&country=ES&userId=2439630&uses=1&autoassign=1&platform=ALL",
    false,
    @httpPost2CallStatus,
    @httpPost2Response
)
```

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: Error 500 Maybe this error is made by server?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like it is not an issue with the function, but instead something either with the URL you are posting to, settings on receiving server to receive data, or the data you are posting is incorrectly formatted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the Content-Type `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` instead of `"multipart/form-data"`.